# Usar arquivo .ini para salvar dados de conexão ao DB?

Tags: php

Olá,

Usar arquivo .ini para salvar dados de conexão do banco de dados é uma prática ruim?

Comment: so isso nao basta. Voce precisa configurar seu servidor web pra nao deixar fazer o download do arquivo digitando o caminho no browser

Comment: O que não é difícil fazer @IsraelZebulon, mas usar arquivo txt é realmente mais difícil de dar manutenção. Usar uma classe estática ou constantes, com include que nem na resposta abaixo, é mais simples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é questão de boa pratica ou pratica ruim, é questão de se sabe como esta fazendo, por exemplo no laravel a senha do banco principal fica no `.env` (este arquivo é basicamente um formato `.ini` só que usa uma extensão customizada):

- https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example#L14

Mas a pasta aonde ficam os dados não esta disponível via HTTP (acesso via url do site), pois os endereços ficam apontados para dentro da pasta `./public`

Claro que tem programdores (pseudo-programadores) que não entendem a lógica da estutura da pasta do laravel e colocam tudo dentro de `public_html` ou `www` na hospedagem e criam um `.htaccess` sem ter muito entendimento sobre isto, o que por vezes pode acabar permitindo acessar o `.env` via URL `http://site/.env`

Agora se sabe o que esta fazendo, que o seu `.ini` ficará isolado em um lugar que só os scripts e o administrador vão conseguir acessar então não teria problema algum.

Claro que pode também optar por criar um `.php` com `define`, por exemplo:

Tem um arquivo chamado `config.php` com este conteudo:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', '12*.***.***');
define('DB_USER', 'foo');
define('DB_PASS', 'bar');
define('DB_MAIN', 'banco');
```

Então ele deve ser incluido em todos scripts principais com:

```
<?php

require_once 'config.php';

...
```

No mysql usaria algo como (apenas um exemplo aproximado):

```
 $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_MAIN);
```

PDO (apenas um exemplo aproximado):

```
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=' + DB_HOST + ';dbname=' + DB_MAIN, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
```

Então se o usuário acessar via URL `http://site/config.php` irá ficar visivel somente uma página em branco.

Uma coisa importante a se fazer é sempre desligar os erros no output e manter somente no log, sentando no php.ini:

```
 display_errors=off
```

Isto porque alguns depuradores, como do Laravel e outros frameworks podem exibir partes do código, na verdade é um baita erro ligar os depuradores em produção (no seu servidor de hospedagem), depuradores devem ser usado somente em ambientes seguros, como na sua maquina.